# How to split by a delimiter and then concatenate to form a new string based on a substring in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in pandas with file paths. I want to split each path with a delimiter ("/"), find the element containing a particular substring, and then finally concatenate that element and everything to the right of that element.

In the following two examples, I want to return the sub-section of the path from the element containing ".eml" and everything to the right of it.

**Input:** /ABC0001/XYZ-0001/Doe_John/Doe_John_20180912/201980912/0/Doe-1.eml/Top of Email/FWD: Email Subject

**Output:** /Doe-1.eml/Top of Email/FWD: Email Subject

**Input:** /ABC12345/XYZ-54321/Doe_Jane/201980912/0/Jane.eml/Emails/Top of Email/RE: Email Subject

**Output:** /Jane.eml/Emails/Top of Email/RE: Email Subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas Series apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) is your friend here. Make a custom function to do the job and use `apply` to apply it on each row of the column.

Suppose you want to save the extracted output into a column called `'output'`:

```
def aftereml(x):
    ll = x.split('/')
    i = None
    for j, stg in enumerate(ll):
        if '.eml' in stg:
            i = j
            break
    if i is not None:
        return '/' + '/'.join(ll[i:])
    else:
        return x

df['output'] = df['filepath'].apply(aftereml)
```

Here, in case no `'.eml'` substring is found, the full string is returned, change the behaviour accordingly to your needs (if you are sure that this never occurs, you can drop this check).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is split at '/' and then join all the elements in the string after '.eml'. Check the below code:

```
a='/ABC12345/XYZ-54321/Doe_Jane/201980912/0/Jane.eml/Emails/Top of Email/RE: Email Subject'
a=a.split('/')
for i in range(0,len(a)):
if '.eml' in a[i]:
    b='/'+'/'.join(a[i:])
```

Output:

```
print(b)
'/Jane.eml/Emails/Top of Email/RE: Email Subject'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without splitting and joining by using [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

```
def find(s, what):
    i = s.find(what)
    if i >= 0:
        j = s.rfind('/', 0, i)
        return s[s.rfind('/', 0, i):] if j >= 0 else s
    else:
        return s

df['Output'] = df.Input.apply(find, args=('.eml',))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame({'Input': ['/ABC0001/XYZ-0001/Doe_John/Doe_John_20180912/201980912/0/Doe-1.eml/Top of Email/FWD: Email Subject', '/ABC12345/XYZ-54321/Doe_Jane/201980912/0/Jane.eml/Emails/Top of Email/RE: Email Subject']})
>>> def srs_reg(txt):
...     mask = "([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+\.eml\/.*)"
...     return "/" + re.search(mask, text).group(1)
...
>>> df['Output'] = df['Input'].apply(srs_reg)
>>> df
                                               Input                                      Output
0  /ABC0001/XYZ-0001/Doe_John/Doe_John_20180912/2...  /Doe-1.eml/Top of Email/FWD: Email Subject
1  /ABC12345/XYZ-54321/Doe_Jane/201980912/0/Jane....  /Doe-1.eml/Top of Email/FWD: Email Subject
```